# jquery $(document).live function implementation

Tags: jquery, document, live

I have this piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rating-stars").ratingbig({
        callback: function (value, link) {
            var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id').split("_");
            var tip = $('#rating-result_' + element[1]);
            tip[0].data = value;
            $('#rating-result_' + element[1]).html(ratingMnemos[tip[0].data] || ratingMnemos[0]);
        },
        focus: function (value, link) {
            var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id').split("_");
            var tip = $('#rating-result_' + element[1]);
            tip.html(ratingMnemos[value]);
        },
        blur: function (value, link) {
            var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id').split("_");
            var tip = $('#rating-result_' + element[1]);
            tip[0].data = value;
            $('#rating-result_' + element[1]).html(ratingMnemos[tip[0].data] || ratingMnemos[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

And i add some code via ajax to the page. nu the rating is not working on the new added elements in the page. I'm stuck because I can't find a way to trigger the function when the new elements are added in the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried debugging your app with JavaScript debugger like Firebug to see how your Ajax call executes?

Comment: What does jQuery.fn.ratingbig do?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that he is adding additional items with a class of `rating-stars` after document load that need this plugin applied to them. The only solution in this case will be to do it every time a new item is added, such as in the callback of a `.load()` or `.ajax()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question was what to do when you add new items with the class `rating-stars` to the page after the initial function call.

The code you provided runs only once, after the initial page load. You will have to call something similar *after* adding new items to the page in order to apply it to those new items. For example, during your AJAX callback.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  // Omitted actual call
  success: function(){
    // Omitted additional callback actions
    applyRatingBig();
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  applyRatingBig();
});

function applyRatingBig() {
// Consider adding code to ensure that this only gets called once per object - for example, you could set a flag once it has been called for a given object

$(".rating-stars").ratingbig({
    callback: function (value, link) {
        var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id').split("_");
        var tip = $('#rating-result_' + element[1]);
        tip[0].data = value;
        $('#rating-result_' + element[1]).html(ratingMnemos[tip[0].data] || ratingMnemos[0]);
    },
    focus: function (value, link) {
        var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id').split("_");
        var tip = $('#rating-result_' + element[1]);
        tip.html(ratingMnemos[value]);
    },
    blur: function (value, link) {
        var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id').split("_");
        var tip = $('#rating-result_' + element[1]);
        tip[0].data = value;
        $('#rating-result_' + element[1]).html(ratingMnemos[tip[0].data] || ratingMnemos[0]);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I tried already a solution similar to David suggestion but for some reason was not working. Hoever the solution i found ( very simple) was to simply put the script in a function that already has click delegation  with document.on('click', function( ( because the rating function was hidden at the moment of creation) and made visibile after a click event. Thank for your help is very very nice to see that are still people that can help you in these akward moments of "non solutions"